# getting MSPointerUp events to fire without disabling browser interaction in IE10

Tags: javascript, touch, multi-touch, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to get some code to kick in after the browser has been scrolled.

If I do

```
function handleDown(event) {
   console.log("down");
}

function handleUp(event) {
   console.log("up");
}

window.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", handleDown, false);
window.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", handleUp, false);
```

Along with CSS

```
 html {
    -ms-content-zooming: none; /* Disable pan/zoom */
    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

The events fire properly. However if I remove the overflow:hiddem and scroll the browser then the up event doesn't fire. Is there a way to have the browser respond normally to scrolling via touch but still fire the MSPointerUp event?

Comment: Is an MSPointerCancel event fired instead when the scroll starts, by any chance?

Comment: I have the same problem. MSPointerCancel is not a solution since it fires directly when starting to scroll, not when the scroll is completed and the pointer is "released".

Answer (score 1):

You can use style="-ms-touch-action: pan-y", so you will able to scroll webView, and have horizontal MSEvents, more options you can find here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh767313.aspx